# what exactly is .get() returning from Google App Engine datastore? What is the "first" result?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My kind looks like this:

```
class userScore(db.Model):
    # stores info about each users' score
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    username = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    score = db.StringProperty(required=False)
```

I retrieve a given user's score like this:

```
username = 'John'
userScore.all().filter('username = ', username).get()
```

This works well when each user has only one entity with one score. But what if I have multiple entities for the same user with different scores? E.g.

```
created username score
1/30/16 John 100
1/31/16 John 99
1/28/16 John 101
```

**Question**:

Will .get() always return the most recent result, i.e., 1/31/16 John 99?

I have been reading about [model.get()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get) but I can't figure it out.

**Update/details**

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_get), .get() "executes the query and returns the first result, or None if no results are found". What I am trying to understand is what **first** means exactly. Thank you to [Dan Cornilescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495081/dan-cornilescu) for helping me clarify what I am actually asking about.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The `.get()` you have in your code is not a `model.get()`, which is likely what throws you off.

The `userScore.all()` is a [`Model.all()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_all), which returns a `Query`, so your `.get()` is actually a [`Query.get()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_get) which will return a list of matching results that can be sorted/ordered if you so desire, using [`Query.order()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_order).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think .get() returns the first result.
"Executes the query and returns the first result, or None if no results are found." The problem is that I do not know what "the first" means in the context of my question.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_get

Comment: I don't think you can rely on `first` being anything related to the values of the entity properties *unless* you specify an order. `First` could, for example, depend on the order in which the entities were inserted into the index, which may have nothing to do with the actual entity property values. And the order may change, for example if one of the entities is re-written, even if the property values don't change (I'm not sure if this is true, but without `first` being specifically described one way or another it *could* very well be).

Comment: I see. I think learning the definition of "first" is what I am actually asking about. I was displaying the results of .get() to my users and now I want to figure out whether they always saw the most recent result/score or not. I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: Imagine you fetch(10), it returns a list. Now get() is equal to fetch(1)[0]. There is no ordering if you don't define one.